# Sales Data for all customers and products

Tags: mysql

The query should return all customers ,even customers without invoices and also products,even those products that were not sold.Print NA for null customers or product or null quantity .
Order by customerid, productid, and invoiceid

Tables:

Customer

```
id
customer_name
city_id
customer_address
contact_person
email
phone
```

Product

```
id
sku
product_name
product_description
current_price
quantity_in_stock
```

Invoice

```
id
invoice_number
customer_id
user_account_id
total_price
time_issued
time_due
time_paid
time_canceled
time_refunded
```

Invoice_Item

```
id
invoice_id
product_id
quantity
price
line_total_price
```

I have tried this

```
select 
   coalesce((c.customer_name), "NA"),
   coalesce((p.product_name),"NA"),
   coalesce((ii.quantity),"NA")
from customer c 
left join invoice i on c.id=i.customer_id
join invoice_item ii on  ii.invoice_id=i.id
left join product p on p.id=ii.product_id
order by i.customer_id,ii.product_id,ii.id
```

Comment: try to make a complete [mre] and create tabke thgat is better to read as that what you provided

Comment: The problem description is very vague. Try to add a minimal set of input data, and desired output.  (and, Please, describe why the statement that you tried is not OK in your opinion)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.customer_name, a.product_name, a.quantity
FROM
    (SELECT 
        customer.id AS customer_id,
            product.id AS product_id,
            invoice_item.id AS invoice_item_id,
            IFNULL(name, 'N/A') customer_name,
            IFNULL(`Product Name`, 'N/A') product_name,
            IFNULL(quantity, 0) quantity
    FROM
        ((customer
    LEFT JOIN invoice ON customer.id = invoice.customer_id)
    LEFT JOIN invoice_item ON invoice_item.invoice_id = invoice.id)
    FULL OUTER JOIN product ON invoice_item.product_id = product.id) a
ORDER BY customer_id , product_id , invoice_item_id;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT 
    a.customer_name, a.product_name, a.quantity
FROM
    (SELECT 
        customer.id AS customer_id,
            product.id AS product_id,
            invoice_item.id AS invoice_item_id,
            IFNULL(name, 'N/A') customer_name,
            IFNULL(`Product Name`, 'N/A') product_name,
            IFNULL(quantity, 0) quantity
    FROM
        ((customer
    LEFT JOIN invoice ON customer.id = invoice.customer_id)
    LEFT JOIN invoice_item ON invoice_item.invoice_id = invoice.id)
    LEFT JOIN product ON invoice_item.product_id = product.id UNION ALL SELECT 
        customer.id,
            product.id,
            invoice_item.id,
            IFNULL(name, 'N/A') customer_name,
            IFNULL(`Product Name`, 'N/A') product_name,
            IFNULL(quantity, 0) quantity
    FROM
        ((product
    LEFT JOIN invoice_item ON invoice_item.product_id = product.id)
    LEFT JOIN invoice ON invoice_item.invoice_id = invoice.id)
    LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.id = invoice.customer_id) a
ORDER BY customer_id , product_id , invoice_item_id;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?